# React Native Navigation: Navigate to a screen from outside a React component

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/basic-navigation#navigating-in-a-stack
indicates that pushing a new screen to the stack requires the current screen's `componentId`. My use case is to allow navigating based on certain events emitted by a native module. As such, `componentId` won't be available to me, since the event listener would reside outside any React component screen. Is there any way to navigate to a screen from outside in RNN? Or even get the current `componentId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a command event listener to store the current `componentId` in closure.

```js
let currentComponentId;

Navigation.events().registerCommandListener((name, params) => {
  if (name === 'push') {
    currentComponentId = params.componentId;
  }
});

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot(rootRouteConfig);

  EventEmitter.addListener('navigate', (name) => {
    Navigation.push(currentComponentId, {
      component: {
        name,
      },
    });
  });
});
```